# nodemailer: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in-v3.mailjet.com

Tags: node.js, smtp, nestjs, nodemailer, mailjet

I am currently working on an **API in NestJs** using mail sending with **Mailjet** service.
Sending mail works locally, in a docker container, but not in the pod via my Kubernetes cluster.

The error on the API is as follows:

```
error: 22:45:35.712+00:00 [ExceptionsHandler] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in-v3.mailjet.com
```

I put you the configuration used for SMTP with Mailjet below with the function used to send mail. (I'm also using handlebars for email templating).

```js
// src/providers/mailer/mailer.provider.ts

...
{
  transport: {
    host: mailerConfigService.host, // in-v3.mailjet.com
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: mailerConfigService.user, // 9f85b17...
      pass: mailerConfigService.password, // bffc4e...
    },
  },
  defaults: {
    from: mailerConfigService.from, // contact@example.com
  },
  template: {
    dir: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'mails', 'templates'),
    adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
    options: {
      strict: true,
    },
  },
}
...
```

```js
// src/mails/mail.service.ts

public async sendMailConfirmation(user: UserSerializer) {
  return await this.mailerService.sendMail({
    to: user.email,
    subject: 'Confirmez votre adresse email',
    template: './mail-verification',
    context: {
      frontUrl: this.appConfigService.frontUrl, // https://example.com
      firstName: user.firstName, // John
      code: user.emailValidationCode, // 3456
    },
  });
}
```

I tried to do a `nslookup` directly from the pod, but everything works, at least no error. The result of the commande:

```
/usr/app # nslookup in-v3.mailjet.com
Server:         10.32.0.10
Address:        10.32.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
in-v3.mailjet.com       canonical name = in.mailjet.com
Name:   in.mailjet.com
Address: 104.199.96.85

Non-authoritative answer:
in-v3.mailjet.com       canonical name = in.mailjet.com
```

I have exhausted all my cards, and I admit I no longer have any idea on this subject.
I hope you will be able to help me! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello everyone, fixed by using raw text instead of config. Maybe a wrong configuration from my part.